# SQL - Pass Columns to Rows

Tags: sql

I will want your help. I have one exemple table in SQL(MS SQL Server 2017). I extract one excel file to table. The columns [13],[17], [18] and [19], are columns created by extracting from excel.

I have more dates, here only have 1 exemple with 3 dates.

| [13] | [17] | [18] | [19] |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 01/04/2020 | 02/04/2020 | 03/04/2020 |
| Total | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| Asset | 423 | 435 | 533 |
| Revenue | 73 | 73 | 76 |

I Want:

| Indicator | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Total | 01/04/2020 | 100 |
| Total | 02/04/2020 | 200 |
| Total | 03/04/2020 | 300 |
| Asset | 01/04/2020 | 423 |
| Asset | 02/04/2020 | 435 |
| Asset | 03/04/2020 | 533 |
| Revenue | 01/04/2020 | 73 |
| Revenue | 02/04/2020 | 73 |
| Revenue | 03/04/2020 | 76 |

Comment: Please add the example data as formatted text, not images : [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Please add any SQL you've attempted, and why it didn't work.  Please state which RDBMS product and version you're using *(MySQL 5.x, MySQL 8.0, MS SQL Server 2017, Oracle 18c, etc, etc)*

Comment: Is that date column static or dynamic? Do you have only those 3 dates always as columns?

Answer (score 0):

Start with least complexity - this will get the output - but not with finesse.
The data needs maturing with some synthetic data sets to get off the ground - two tables each with two columns.

A pivot would require same extra synthetic meta data to support -- but before starting to get a complex pivot with dynamic sql - start with this one to enable baselining workable data sets

**Indicator Orders**  - to enable the indicators to output in the preferred order
Indicator Order (int)
Indicator Name  (varchar)

**Dates**
[DatePeriodId] smallint, [DatePeriod] varchar, [Date]

The DatePeriod is the column name from the original source data ([17],[18], [19]

This table needs all dates and column names added per the original source

**Then**

select columns [13 , 17] union [13 , 18] union [13, 19] and cross join to the dates table
use a row_number leaning on the Indicator Orders to generate the preferred row output order

Full CTE_ fiddle that works in any SQL Server as follows :
(RowNum is tricky to remove because there is nothing else to order by

```
with 
        [cte_allrecs] as (
        select [13] = null      ,  [17] = '01/04/2020', [18] = '02/04/2020', [19] = '03/04/2020'  union
        select [13] = 'Total' ,  [17] = '100',        [18] = '200',        [19] = '300'         union
        select [13] = 'Asset' ,  [17] = '423',        [18] = '435',        [19] = '533'         union
        select [13] = 'Revenue', [17] = '73',         [18] = '73',         [19] = '76' 
    ) , [cte_IndicatorOrder] as (
        select [IndOrd] = 10, [Indicator] = 'Total' union
        select [IndOrd] = 20, [Indicator] = 'Asset' union
        select [IndOrd] = 30, [Indicator] = 'Revenue'
    ) , [cte_dates] as (
        select [DatePeriodId] = 1, [DatePeriod] = '17', [Date] = '01/04/2020' union
        select [DatePeriodId] = 2, [DatePeriod] = '18', [Date] = '02/04/2020' union
        select [DatePeriodId] = 3, [DatePeriod] = '19', [Date] = '03/04/2020'
    ) , [cte_Measures] as (
        select [Indicator] = isnull([cte_allrecs].[13],'Date'), [n_Date].[Date], [Value] = [cte_allrecs].[17] 
          from [cte_allrecs] cross join (select [Date] from [cte_dates] where [DatePeriod] = '17') [n_Date]
        union
        select [Indicator] = isnull([cte_allrecs].[13],'Date'), [n_Date].[Date], [Value] = [cte_allrecs].[18] 
          from [cte_allrecs] cross join (select [Date] from [cte_dates] where [DatePeriod] = '18') [n_Date]
        union
        select [Indicator] = isnull([cte_allrecs].[13],'Date'),  [n_Date].[Date], [Value] = [cte_allrecs].[19] 
          from [cte_allrecs] cross join (select [Date] from [cte_dates] where [DatePeriod] = '19') [n_Date]
   ) select [RowNum] = row_number() over (order by [cte_IndicatorOrder].[IndOrd], convert(date,[cte_Measures].[Date],103))
             , [cte_Measures].*
          from [cte_Measures] 
          inner join [cte_IndicatorOrder] on [cte_IndicatorOrder].[Indicator] = [cte_Measures].[Indicator]
```

Comment: Helo irnerd, Thanks your help. I have 1 table create with values. Can you help me build query indicated to table?

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TESTE](
[13] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[17] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[18] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[19] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[110] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[111] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[112] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[113] [nvarchar](255) NULL
) ON [DATA]

Comment: INSERT [dbo].[TESTE] ([13], [17], [18], [19], [110], [111], [112], [113]) VALUES (N'INDICATORS', N'01/04/2020', N'02/04/2020', N'03/04/2020', N'04/04/2020', N'05/04/2020', N'06/04/2020', N'07/04/2020')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TESTE] ([13], [17], [18], [19], [110], [111], [112], [113]) VALUES (N'Total', N'496', N'508', N'609', N'560', N'483', N'588', N'496')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TESTE] ([13], [17], [18], [19], [110], [111], [112], [113]) VALUES (N'ASSET', N'423', N'435', N'533', N'492', N'415', N'520', N'425')

Comment: GO
INSERT [dbo].[TESTE] ([13], [17], [18], [19], [110], [111], [112], [113]) VALUES (N'REVENUE', N'73', N'73', N'76', N'68', N'68', N'68', N'71')

Comment: with [cte_allrecs] as (select * from [dbo].[TESTE] )  

Then build up the cte_dates subset to include dates assigned to columns 110 through 113

Then build up the cte_measures.

Realistically this is a challenge more fitting for python -  if you don't know the column names up front then a pandas dataframe will get you out of trouble.  

If SQL is the only approach - then push back on the structure of the data source to be more useable.